# python: binding via kerberos to the ldaps port

Tags: python, ldap, kerberos, sasl, gssapi

I can connect to an Active Directory server using the ldap port and SASL (using gssapi to do kerberos) as follows:

```
import ldap, ldap.sasl, sys

server    = 'ldap://server.domain.tld'
sasl_auth = ldap.sasl.sasl({} ,'GSSAPI')
conn      = ldap.initialize(server, trace_level=0)

conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS,0)  # for AD servers, don't chase referrals via anonymous bind
conn.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3  # Set protocol version to LDAPv3 to enable SASL bind!

conn.sasl_interactive_bind_s("", sasl_auth)
```

All of that works as desired.  (Error checking left out for brevity.)  But if I want to instead connect to the SSL port by changing the server string to:

```
server    = 'ldaps://server.domain.tld'
```

the bind succeeds but my connection is reported as closed when I tried to do the next thing such as:

```
print('Result of Who Am I? ext. op:',repr(conn.whoami_s()))
```

I get:

```
ldap.SERVER_DOWN: {'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server", 'errno': 5, 'info': 'Input/output error'}
```

even though the bind didn't raise any exceptions.  "ldap://" works.  "ldaps://" doesn't.

Does this only work via regular port + TLS, or am I missing some part of the incantation that is necessary for the ldaps port when doing kerberos?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my own question.

If you check out this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/989e0748-0953-455d-9d37-d08dfbf3998b

You find the following text:

> While Active Directory permits SASL binds to be performed on an
>   SSL/TLS-protected connection, it does not permit the use of SASL-layer
>   encryption/integrity verification mechanisms on such a connection.

So I think the answer to my question is that because the python-ldap module does encryption/integrity verification, and not JUST authentication, you can't do SASL and SSL/TLS at the same time.  So you can't also do a start-tls on the "ldap" port, and you can't connect to the "ldaps" (SSL) port and use SASL at all.

Comment: Please self-mark your answer as "answered".  (Click the check mark to the left of the answer)

Comment: It wouldn't let me do it the same day I posted it.  (Doing it now.)

Comment: There is a related fix in Cyrus libsasl: https://github.com/cyrusimap/cyrus-sasl/pull/603